# How to correct for no grammar constraints error

Tags: java, xml

I have a simple XML document that is flagged (correctly) in Eclipse as having no grammar.  I use the file to preload a database on initialisation.  Is there a "generic" DTD or Schema that I could apply to this document (and similar - I have over 15 of them) to eliminate this warning and be more correct in my XML structure?

```
<AbnormalFlags>
    <AbnormalFlag> 
        <code>H</code> 
        <description>High</description>
    </AbnormalFlag>
    <AbnormalFlag> 
        <code>L</code> 
        <description>Low</description>
    </AbnormalFlag>
    <AbnormalFlag> 
        <code>A</code> 
        <description>Abnormal</description>
    </AbnormalFlag>
</AbnormalFlags>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this on top of your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
```